# Extract email metadata with VBA script

Tags: vba, email, excel

I have a folder full of emails that are a custom message class (iXOS-Archive, related to OpenText Enterprise Archive). Each email has a custom metadata property, visible within Outlook, called "Document Identifier". I'm trying to extract this from the emails using a VBA script. I found a script that extracts common metadata (To, From, Subject etc.) from the emails and writes it to Excel. This works well.

http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/getting_a_list_of_file_names_using_vba/

I've tried debugging the script and looking within the email properties, but I cannot find any collection that contains custom metadata.

Does anyone know how I can access the custom metadata through the VBA script?

Answer (score 2):

You will probably **not** be able to do this using a `FileSystemObject` or `DIR` function (as given in the code you linked to, above).

I am unable to test without a suitable example, but this might work:

1. Bind Outlook to Excel
2. Open the MSG file in Outlook
3. Use the Outlook object model to review the MSG file's `.ItemProperties`

Practically speaking you will set this up in a loop, similar to your example code, but for the sake of testing, try it out on a single file and see if this will help you.

```
'Requires reference to Outlook object model
Sub foo()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim properties As Outlook.ItemProperties
Dim p As Long

Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set msg = olApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\your filename.msg")

Set properties = msg.ItemProperties

For p = 0 To properties.Count - 1
    Debug.Print properties(p).Name

Next

Set msg = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

This should print the list of `ItemProperties` in the Immediate window, scroll through that list and check to see if the one you're looking for -- "Document Identifier" -- is included. If so, then this should work and you can modify as needed to do whatever it is you want to do with that information.

I cannot be of further assistance unless you can provide a test/sample version of this email format.

Cheers.

Comment: This does print the ItemProperties, but doesn't include the custom property I'm looking for. Are there any other collections containing custom properties that you know of? Could the custom message class be related here? I also noticed that when debugging and exploring the message properties (msg variable in your code), the email was inserted into my Outlook mailbox. From here I could see the "Document Identifier" property having configured the view to display it. This is great but I have 20,000 emails so can't do this one by one!

Comment: Refer to my last comment in the answer: I can't assist further unless I can see an email in this format. I, like a lot of vba developers, don't *know* all the answers right away.  But I am good at debugging and figuring out how to solve them on principle and by browsing the object model reference.  Looping 20,000 files should be a trivial tweak to this code really, with a Do/Loop statement. Let me know if I can help :)